# i am getting null value from a function in model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I need to select a employee detail using employee id and store the selected detail in another table. I have a function in my controller file as given below

```
 public function delete()
    {
        //product id 
        $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $data_to_store = $this->employee_model->get_employees_by_id($id);
        $data = array('id'=> $data_to_store['id'],
         'emp_first_name' => $data_to_store['emp_first_name'],
                    'emp_last_name' =>  $data_to_store['emp_last_name'],
                    'emp_email_id' =>  $data_to_store['emp_email_id'],
                    'emp_emergency_contact' =>  $data_to_store['emp_emergency_contact'],          
                    'category' =>  $data_to_store['category'],
                    'emp_id_card' => $data_to_store['emp_id_card'],
                     'emp_time_in' =>  $data_to_store['emp_time_in'],
                     'emp_time_out' =>  $data_to_store['emp_time_out'],
                    'emp_date_of_hire' =>  $data_to_store['emp_date_of_hire'],
                    'emp_date_of_termination' =>  $data_to_store['emp_date_of_termination'],
                     'emp_date_of_rehire' =>  $data_to_store['emp_date_of_rehire'],
                     'emp_reference_num' =>  $data_to_store['emp_reference_num'],

                    'emp_service_limitation' => $data_to_store['emp_service_limitation'],
                    'chair_renter' => $data_to_store['chair_renter']

        );
        $this->employee_model->store_deleted_employee($data);

        redirect('admin/employee');
    }
```

In this function i am getting the employee id and call a function get_employee_by_id($id) in my model file. 
My model file

```
public function get_employees_by_id($id)
    {
    $this->db->select('employee.id');
        $this->db->select('employee.emp_first_name');
        $this->db->select('employee.emp_last_name');
        $this->db->select('employee.emp_email_id');
        $this->db->select('employee.emp_emergency_contact');
        $this->db->select('employee.category');
                $this->db->select('employee.emp_id_card');
        $this->db->select('employee.emp_time_in');
        $this->db->select('employee.emp_time_out');
        $this->db->select('employee.emp_date_of_hire');
                $this->db->select('employee.emp_date_of_termination');
                        $this->db->select('employee.emp_date_of_rehire');
                                $this->db->select('employee.emp_reference_num');
        $this->db->select('employee.emp_service_limitation');
        $this->db->select('employee.chair_renter');

        $this->db->from('employee');
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();  


    }
```

By calling this function I am getting the following error.

```
Error Number: 1048

Column 'emp_id_card' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `deleted_employee` (`id`, `emp_first_name`, `emp_last_name`, `emp_email_id`, `emp_emergency_contact`, `category`, `emp_id_card`, `emp_time_in`, `emp_time_out`, `emp_date_of_hire`, `emp_date_of_termination`, `emp_date_of_rehire`, `emp_reference_num`, `emp_service_limitation`, `chair_renter`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\elfanto\elfanto_billing\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Can someone help me code.

**edit 01**

```
 public function delete_confirm()
    {

        $id = $this->uri->segment(4);

        $this->employee_model->delete_employee($id);
        redirect('admin/employee');
    }
```

I need to call this function when that function action overs..

Comment: `print_r($data_to_store)` what is the result of it in controller???

Comment: I am using Dreamweaver and google chrome to see the result. when i use this print_r($data_to_store) statement i do not see any changes.

Comment: does Column `emp_id_card` needs to be filled or is it an optional on your application? if it is optional, why not just make a default value on your database table?

Comment: i am getting this in my browser..Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 676 [emp_first_name] => ghdy [emp_last_name] => yed [emp_email_id] => [emp_emergency_contact] => 0 [category] => [emp_id_card] => 0 [emp_time_in] => [emp_time_out] => [emp_date_of_hire] => 2000-09-09 [emp_date_of_termination] => 2001-09-09 [emp_date_of_rehire] => [emp_reference_num] => [emp_service_limitation] => dont_permit [chair_renter] => 0 ) )

Comment: it is optional @roullie

Comment: Change  `return $query->result_array();` to  `return   $query->row_array();` in model

Comment: after this change in my model I am getting this in my browser. stdClass Object ( [id] => 676 [emp_first_name] => ghdy [emp_last_name] => yed [emp_email_id] => [emp_emergency_contact] => 0 [category] => [emp_id_card] => 0 [emp_time_in] => [emp_time_out] => [emp_date_of_hire] => 2000-09-09 [emp_date_of_termination] => 2001-09-09 [emp_date_of_rehire] => [emp_reference_num] => [emp_service_limitation] => dont_permit [chair_renter] => 0 )

Comment: Now i am getting my output.. thank you all and @Saty

Comment: `$query->row_array();` solve your problem????

Comment: now i need to another function in my controller in this code..if($this->employee_model->store_deleted_employee($data) == TRUE)
  {
   
  } i need to call another function in same controller is it possible?

Comment: how to do it in the if condition?

Comment: I have edited my post please kindly verify it.

Comment: It is better to edit post a new question!!!

Comment: i can post a new question only after 90mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result_array();` This method returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced. Typically you’ll use this in a `foreach loop`:

Intesd of it you return

```
return $query->row_array();
```

it returns an array as per your controller code